# How to perform Data Type Converion in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query given below in which I want to convert it's type.

```
Select
CONVERT(date, o.OrderDate)as OrderDate
From Orders
```

I am writing following statement:

```
var r= (
                    from o in db.Orders
                    select new { o.OrderNumber,o.Name,o.State,Convert.ToDateTime(o.OrderNumber) }
                ).ToList();
```

So it gives error:

> Error 18  Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type
>   members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or
>   member access.

How do I deal with this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

That's mean that you need to assign *names* to the values of that anonymous memeber.

For example:

```
from o in db.Orders
select new { OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber, Name = o.Name,
            State = o.State, Date = Convert.ToDateTime(o.OrderNumber) }
```

Comment: *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method*. Not sure it pertains to my issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *name* the members of your anonymous type. Sometimes the compiler will pick a name automatically (for example when you are assigning properties), but sometimes, it's not possible:

```
                                            vvvv
 new { o.OrderNumber, o.Name, o.State, OrderDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(o.OrderNumber) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var r= (from o in db.Orders
    select new { o.OrderNumber,o.Name,o.State,
                 OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(o.OrderDate) }
                ).ToList();
```

Edit

Try this to materialize the query first.

```
var query = db.Orders.ToList().Select(o => new {
o.OrderNumber,
o.Name,
o.State,
OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(o.OrderNumber)
}).ToList();
```

Comment: The error I get *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method*

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your LINQ to Entities query it is converted to an equivalent database-side code using the underlying data provider.

It so happens that there is no mapping from `Convert.ToDateTime()` to SQL Server equivalent.

Instead, you would do this in memory after you've retrieved the data as follows.

```
var r= 
    (from o in db.Orders
    select new { o.OrderNumber, o.Name, o.State })
    .AsEnumerable() // Execute the above query
    .Select(order => new { order.OrderNumber, order.Name, order.State, OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(order.OrderNumber)})
    .ToList();
```

(You could also split this into two queries for readability.)

There are also functions you can use in your L2E queries that are converted to their database equivalents.

See the [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) classes for more information.

Comment: But it gives error: *The error I get LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)*

Comment: Did you copy the code correctly? The `Convert.ToDateTime()` is operating on Linq to Objects and NOT on Linq to Entities.

Comment: I am new into LINQ. My Main Concern is Type Casting which I mentioned on Original SQL Query. I am looking for equivalent in LINQ